# Problem getting the most recent uploaded videos of a channel using the YouTube Data API V3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using the Google APIS explorer's `youtube.playlistItems.list`.
I've set the `part` parameter to `"snippet"`, the `maxResults` to `10`, the `playlistId` to `UUzoVCacndDCfGDf41P-z0iA` which is the `uploads` id for the *JSConf* YouTube channel (the `channelId` is `UCzoVCacndDCfGDf41P-z0iA`), but for some reason I don't see some of the recent videos uploaded on the channel. I assume maybe because the videos are not returned in a particular order?... if so, how can I can make sure that I get the **most recent** uploaded videos that corresponds to a specific `maxResults` value that I specify?

Update: the API works just fine with other channels & the videos are even returned in order which is what I would expect...

Answer (score 1):

Please note the fact that the [PlaylistItems endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) queried for the uploads list of a channel produces an [items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response) list which is ordered by [videoPublishedAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.videoPublishedAt). But the [items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) themselves contains [publishedAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.publishedAt) datetime properties attached.

> [**videos#snippet.publishedAt**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) (datetime)
>
> The date and time that the video was published. *Note that this time might be different than the time that the video was uploaded.* For example, if a video is uploaded as a private video and then made public at a later time, this property will specify the time that the video was made public.

Then the output obtained is fact correct:

```
$ youtube-data \
--playlist=UUzoVCacndDCfGDf41P-z0iA --videos \
--max-results=20 --page=- \
--table --relative-date
09V_JAGTs2E   2   days 14  hours ago    What Tamagotchis Can Teach You About...
Mnc8ck_DuaE   2   days 14  hours ago    How (Not) to Fail at Accessibility -...
UM-RhglTyKA   2   days 14  hours ago    GraphQL, the Domain Way - Thais Corr...
NdKAUXAvt8E   2   days 14  hours ago    The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtle Guid...
g3jwd0kAIDU   2   days 14  hours ago    Improving React Native Performance i...
HkRrJvvnlvU   2   days 14  hours ago    JSParty Live at JSConf Hawaii 2019 o...
I4ugdJRCj9Q   2   days 14  hours ago    Building Up the Electron Project: Te...
F4G2i4eS7x0   2   days 14  hours ago    How to Make Your Website Not Ugly - ...
LFUnn-8IAjQ   2   days 14  hours ago    Where Did All My Servers Go? - Garth...
VGcqkF2XDgA   2   days 14  hours ago    Navigating Unconscious Bias - Emily ...
el9fhSbby5E   2   days 14  hours ago    JavaScript is AsynchroWAT? - Crystal...
JybbgAz3meQ   2   days 14  hours ago    How to Calculate the Phase of the Mo...
_0ij8vY2gzE  11  hours  4   mins ago    Music and Art with ML by Monica Dinc...
Zyoztl_7l7g   5   days 13  hours ago    Navigating the Wild Seas of Native E...
ZMZMMuXRFcE   1    day 11  hours ago    Web Components and the AOM by Léoni...
pEVGAn2qNtU   4   days 13  hours ago    Designing Components for Fun, Profit...
skml8SjOtKg   3   days 12  hours ago    Real World Problems - Internet beyon...
v2Au9Rlj6XM   6   days 14  hours ago    The Browser as a Modular, Networked ...
BBWMIxXqr-E   6   days 13  hours ago    Variable Fonts and the Flexible Natu...
aQBYAkaABkU   5   days 13  hours ago    artistic.css by Agnieszka Naplocha |...
```

If you want to obtain the *latest published* say 10 videos of a particular channel you should query the [Search endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) instead, passing to it proper parameters: `channelId=...`, `maxResults=10` and `order=date`.

The output then would look like the one below:

```
$ youtube-data \
--channel=UCzoVCacndDCfGDf41P-z0iA --videos \
--max-results=10 --page=- \
--table
_0ij8vY2gzE  2019-06-27T02:44:21.000Z  Music and Art with ML by Monica Dincu...
Vk9bPDaZELQ  2019-06-26T12:10:11.000Z  Block, unblock, block! How ad blocker...
ZMZMMuXRFcE  2019-06-26T02:14:07.000Z  Web Components and the AOM by Léonie ...
GhRE3rML9t4  2019-06-25T14:14:55.000Z  CSS Houdini & The Future of Styling b...
JybbgAz3meQ  2019-06-24T22:54:47.000Z  How to Calculate the Phase of the Moo...
UM-RhglTyKA  2019-06-24T22:54:47.000Z  GraphQL, the Domain Way - Thais Corre...
g3jwd0kAIDU  2019-06-24T22:54:47.000Z  Improving React Native Performance in...
I4ugdJRCj9Q  2019-06-24T22:54:47.000Z  Building Up the Electron Project: Tea...
el9fhSbby5E  2019-06-24T22:54:46.000Z  JavaScript is AsynchroWAT? - Crystal ...
NdKAUXAvt8E  2019-06-24T22:54:46.000Z  The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtle Guide...
```